# How should I go about transferring data from an ODBC app to SQL on an hourly basis?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis, odbc, mirror

I'm trying to pull data from an ODBC app to SQL2005(dev ed) DB on an hourly basis.  When I run SSIS the option to import all tables and views is grayed out and forces your to write a query. How would I go about setting up a SSIS integration service to update ALL 250 some tables on an hourly basis.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of database is your ODBC data source pointing to?  SSIS might not give you a GUI for selecting tables/views for all DB types.

Comment: Pervasive SQL for Timberline accounting and estimating

Comment: Right, yep, there's your answer.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you could rephrase your question a little, I am not 100% sure what you are asking here. Are you trying to get data into SQL Server from an application via SSIS with the Data Transform task using an ODBC connection to the Application?

Anyhoo, the simple answer to the MS Access part of your question is "hell no" MS Access is never, ever the answer to anything ;-)

I would be inclined to find out why the tables and views are greyed out and fix that issue. (not enough info in this question to determine why they are greyed out)

Comment: Thanks Tim - When running SSIS "Copy data from one or more tables" is grayed out by design (2000 DTS works). SSIS forces you to write a query to run the data pull. How would one go about an SSIS to import all the tables and views, and then update all the tables and views hourly.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using the Import and Export Wizard.  Go into SQL Server Management Studio, right click on the Database you want to import the data into, and select Tasks -> Import Data.  It will launch the wizard which will walk you through defining the import process.

At the end of the wizard you can choose to execute the import, and even save it as an SSIS package which you can tweak later.